# sidebar routerlink no funciona

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

tengo un sidebar en el cual se genera un  menu de forma dinamica, cuando hago link a cualquier menu
la ruta se modifica pero no cambia o actualiza la pagina:
ejemplo aqui deberia dar error 404 pero se mantiene en la pagina, al pulsar cualquier boton del sidebar pasa exactamente lo mismo. no hace el link a la pagina asignada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<nav class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" style="margin-left: -15px;">
  <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{'active': routerLinkActive}" *ngFor="let m of menu">
        <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="!m.is_father" [routerLink]="m.route" routerLinkActive="true">
          <i [ngClass]="['menu-icon', m.icon ]"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">{{m.name}}</span>
        </a>
        <!--NgIf: Contructor menu depend and Father-->
        <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="m.is_father" (click)="m.active = !m.active" [attr.aria-expanded]="m.active" aria-controls="MenuCollapse">
          <i [ngClass]="['menu-icon', m.icon ]"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">{{m.name}}</span>
          <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" *ngIf="m.is_father" [id]="MenuCollapse" [ngbCollapse]="!m.active">
          <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
            <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let sm of m.submenu"><a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="sm.route" routerLinkActive="active" #dragula="routerLinkActive">{{ sm.name }}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: en este caso se que el uso de routing hace que no deba recargar la pagina pero, no comprendo porque no cambia de componente

Answer (score 0):

La URL de la barra de direcciones del navegador es controlada por el Router de Angular, por lo que un cambio en la URL no significa que se vaya a cargar una página. Por tanto, lo que tienes que hacer en ese caso es crear un componente asociado a la URL `.../error-404` que muestre el mensaje de error que desees mostrar.

Comment: si efectivamente, esta creado pero no me hace la navegacion entre componentes solo carga la url pero no me navega entre ellos, cuando coloco <router-outlet></router-outlet> en el sidebar pareciera hacer algo mas no carga nada.